# WPF Datatemplate Event Handling

Tags: wpf, events, datatemplate

I have a MVVM aaplication using a TreeView that is defined as a data template in a resourcedictionary. I'm struggling to find a way to define a "MouseDoubleClick" event complete with the treenode being clicked.

The base code being used can be seen at https://www.codeproject.com/articles/718022/searchable-wpf-treeview?fid=1852697&df=90&mpp=25&sort=Position&spc=Relaxed&prof=True&view=Normal&fr=51#xx0xx

Comment: Hello, can you please have quick read of this webpage? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm trying to understand the problem, You'r looking for a way to double click a treenode with out it expanding ?

Comment: I'm trying to add a "MouseDoubleClick" event to the TreeView that is defined in a ResourceDictionary. If you look on the codeproject link it would be in the SettingsView.Xaml.

Comment: Anyone? Anyone?